# How can we model variable interactions using neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, interaction

[image: Event rate plotted against month*tenure]

I have 2 independent events as months and tenure and dependent variable 1/0.
Does neural network automatically handles interactions, or do we need to tweak it to handle interactions?

e.g. I want to model that at certain months and tenure combinations event rates are higher than other combinations. I want such combinations to be modeled. Can neural network approximate this surface?